# Wordpress - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I need to implement a date & time picker in a wordpress website but I get a Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker error on any solution I try.

The most convenient for me is the one from this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239204/datepicker-not-supporting-timepicker

Only the wordpress native datepicker and timepicker work.

The files are correctly imported in the webpage source.

Am I missing something here?

Here's my code:

functions.php

```
function wpse_enqueue_datepicker()
{
  // wp_register_script('datetimepicker-js', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/cart/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js');
  // wp_enqueue_script('datetimepicker-js');

  // wp_register_style('datetimepicker-css', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/cart/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css');
  // wp_enqueue_style('datetimepicker-css');

  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-timepicker-addon', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/cart/datetimepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', array());
  wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-timepicker-addon', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/cart/datetimepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css', array());
  wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/cart/datetimepicker/jquery-ui.css', array());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_datepicker');
```

page.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#datetime").datetimepicker({
      timeFormat: "hh:mm",
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  });
</script>
```

EDIT:
I also have the same issue with https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ which is implemented from the commented lines in functions.php

EDIT Solved: get_stylesheet_directory -> get_stylesheet_directory_uri in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

```
You are using datetimepicker when it should be datepicker.

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetime').datepicker({
      viewMode: 'years'
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: datepicker doesn't allow me to pick time, that's why I need datetimepicker.